# How to Read Reg_Binary type values in string format from Registry in python

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

[image: These are registry values of resulted output and i want my output to be chrome.exe it is decoded in edit binary value]

```
from winreg import *

import binascii

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU")

for i in range(1024):

    try:
        name,value,type = EnumValue(aKey,i)
        print(value)
        print("\n")
    except EnvironmentError:                                
        break

CloseKey(aKey)
```

OUTPUT is like this. its for only one value:

```
b'v\x00l\x00c\x00.\x00e\x00x\x00e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x85\x00\x00\x00\x10\x03\x00\x00<\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x00\x00\x00i\x03\x00\x00\x84\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

How can i convert it to string or text?

Comment: You could use [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) if you know the encoding. What do you expect from this data as resulting string?

Comment: Data is the names of Recently used non-metro apps For example(chrome.exe)

Comment: I have added a picture for more simplification

Comment: This cleared things up. I have added an answer on how to extract the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some more data in these registry entries, but they begin with the name of a recently used program file. I found a way to extract that first name, but the entries end with some more data, where I don't know what it is.

The characters are separated by null bytes (`b'\x00`). So we have to extract every second character (I suppose the data is in `value`):

```
value[::2]
```

Then we need to find the first null byte to terminate the string there (otherwise the decoding fails, because of the other data at the end):

```
value[::2].find(b'\x00')
```

The found index can be used to get the part before it and then we call the `decode()` method to make a sting out of the bytes object (`decode()` defaults to utf-8 encoding):

```
value[::2][:value[::2].find(b'\x00')].decode()
```

---

Using your example it would look like the following. The input is your example *OUTPUT*. After using `value[::2]` it look like this:

```
b'vlc.exe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x85\x00\x10\x00<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xa4\x00i\x00\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

And in the end you will get this:

```
'vlc.exe'
```

Comment: while i am trying to code it i am facing error of                                                     value[::2][value[::2].find(b'\x00')].decode()                                                   
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @AliAhmed oh, there was a `:` missing in my code (so it got only one int out of `value`, instead of everything up to `\x00`). Fixed it now.

Comment: vlc.exe

AcroRd32.exe
OpenWith.exe
Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool.exe
{B60C66F3-3F17-4C8F-B0AA-C30C6A086305}
devenv.exe
{DA28A05A-9BB6-43B9-9ACD-4FE4A018D95E}
opera.exe
{17527065-D8DC-4643-96A3-638D3CE99C4A}
mspaint.exe
{82A29CEF-C8BC-4576-AFD8-5B48A62F30A7}
{0E54D3A2-2791-43CF-B2E2-B0FC24BA01A5}
javaw.exe
designer.exe
SnippingTool.exe
chrome.exe
{93ED486F-0D04-4807-8C44-AC26CB6C5D36}

Comment: Thank you so much i nearly completed my task.. :) just i am having these type of  garbage values  {82A29CEF-C8BC-4576-AFD8-5B48A62F30A7}

Comment: @AliAhmed This looks like [UUIDs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier), but I don't know what they show here. If you want to remove them have a look at regular expressions or simply filter the results for entries containing `.exe`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your important time..well appreciated. you are such a nice person.

Comment: I want to decode the MountedDevice value but it is still gibberish and not human readable, I want to get partition and their drive letter mapping but unable to decode